# How to dynamically access target of function object

Tags: c++, c++11, functor

I have a vector of function objects (`std::function`) all derived from a common base class, `base`, as shown below. While iterating over the vector I would like access to and possibly change variables in the target -- for example `test`. At compile time, `std::function::target()` can return a pointer to the original target, but is there a way to do this at run-time -- i.e. dynamically access `test`? The vector of functors could be comprised of an arbitrary number of different target functions. Boost is not an option for this codebase.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

typedef std::function<double(double)> Tfunc;

struct base { bool test; };

struct half : public base {
  template<typename T> T operator()(T x) { return x*0.5; }
};

struct square : public base {
  template<typename T> T operator()(T x) { return x*x; }
};

int main() {
  std::vector<Tfunc> v;
  v.push_back( half() );
  v.push_back( square() );

  v[0].target<half>()->test=false;
  v[1].target<square>()->test=true;

  for (auto &f : v)
    std::cout << f(2.0) << " " << f.target_type().name() << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 4half
4 6square
```

Comment: I believe that this isn't possible with `std::function`.

Comment: yes, it seems so - a bit frustrating since the dynamic typeid is available through `target_type()`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to put the test variable inside the functor using inheritance?  You could compose the functor and the test variable like this:

```
struct math_operation
{
     Tfunc f;
     bool  test;
};

std::vector<math_operation> v;
v.push_back( math_operation() );
v.push_back( math_operation() );
v[0].f = half();
v[1].f = square();
v[0].test = false;
v[1].test = true;
```

Comment: Thanks, that would be one good way to solve the example, although it does not address the problem of accessing the target of the functor. In my scenario I cannot change the structure of the target functions and dynamic access would be handy, but perhaps not possible. [edit: sorry I do not have up-vote privileges!]